# understanding entab example code in k&r

Tags: c, tabs, modulo, kernighan-and-ritchie, entab-detab

I'm teaching myself C and working through K&R. I'm doing exercise 1-21:

> Write a Program entab that replaces strings of blanks by the minimum number of tabs and blanks to acheive the same spacing. Use the same tab stops as for detab.

I was having trouble doing this exercise so I found a solution online but I do not understand it.  Can someone explain how this code works?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define TABINC 8

int main(void)
{
    int nb,nt,pos,c;

    nb = 0;
    nt = 0;

    for(pos=1;(c=getchar())!=EOF;++pos)
        if( c == ' ')
        {
            if((pos % TABINC) != 0)
                ++nb;
            else
            {
                nb = 0;
                ++nt;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            for( ; nt > 0 ; --nt)
                putchar('\t');
            if( c == '\t')
                nb = 0;
            else
                for( ; nb > 0; --nb)
                    putchar(' ');

            putchar(c);

            if(c == '\n')
                pos = 0;
            else if ( c == '\t')
                pos = pos + ( TABINC - (pos -1) % TABINC) - 1;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't see why you'd want to keep track of position. Sounds like the whole things blanks; right?

Comment: I thought the code was correct?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work as you expected? You put lots of words, but not mentioning what exactly is the problem.

Comment: I just don't understand why this code works and would appreciate someone walking me through it

Answer (score 0):

The code is to

- put a tab (`'\t'`) when a space () is encountered at a position that is a multiple of `TABINC`, i.e, the size of the tab.
- when a tab is encountered, the number of spaces is reset. This is to prefer a tab to reach a tabstop

To illustrate:
- a space shown in *
- a tab is shown in

```
column: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
input : * * * * h e l * * w 
output:    <tab>hel<tab>*w
```

In this example, when a space is encountered at every column position which is divisible by the `TABINC`, i.e 4 (in this case), a tab '\t' is inserted. Otherwise space.

Hope this will give you some idea.